# How to display address bar with SSL certificate information in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, ssl, webview, certificate

My app handle payment using webview, there is a requirement to display the address bar and certificate information of the designated payment gateway.

I need a flutter inapp webview with

1. Address bar
   [image]
2. Display certificate information

[image]

I been able to fake the address bar by using TextField, but I can't find any way to display the viewed website's certificate. Is there any plugin or ways that can view these information?

Answer (score 0):

can refer to this sample, and try out at play store/app store. https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_browser_app